# How to get database value and show selected value in dropdown list

Tags: jsp

Form has two fields 
1 text field(for example it is student id) and one 1 dropdown list(cate_id) (rest of them unnecessary discussion here)

Dropdownlist values are come from db as soon as page loaded.

when i submit the jsp page  based on the student id I will get the student object back to the same jsp page and have to render the object values in form fields.

the problem I'm facing is when i submit the page it not showing student's cate_id in dropdownlist.(showing all cate_ids)

example:

student has entered 100 in  the text field, his corresponding category id(eg. fresher,graduate or junior etc) should be displayed in dropdownlist not all the values in the db.

Here is the my code.

/*

```
  <sql:setDataSource driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
               url="jdbc:odbc:lab"
               var="localSource" 
               />

 <sql:query dataSource="${localSource}" 
       sql="select cate_id,cate_desc from category"
       var="result" />
 <select name="cate_id">
 <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="r">
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${r.cate_id eq a }"> // I got a value from request.getattribute
    <option value="${r.cate_id}" selected="selected">${r.cate_desc}</option>
    </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
  <option value="${r.cate_id}">${r.cate_desc}</option>
  </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
   </c:forEach>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope is the issue here

```
 <c:when test="${r.cate_id eq a }">

 I havent created usebean variable earlier.
  just created variable with name a  in scriptlet.

  Created usebean variable. It is working now

 <jsp:useBean id="student" class="student.Student" scope="application"/>


 In dropdownlist code modified as


<c:when test="${r.cate_id eq student.cate_id}">
```